# Floatable centered and non-splittable lstlisting

Tags: floats, listings

I've been looking around and tried various setups but have yet to found the solution.

I'm trying to define a `lstlisting` environment that is a float, is centered in the page, and cannot be broken across pages, without using `captionof`. Using the `figure`, `center`, and `varwidth` environments to encapsulate the `lstlisting`environment works. However, it requires to use `captionof` from the `caption`package outside the `lstlisting`, which changes the *look* (size) and *behavior* (width of the caption box, perhaps due to the `varwidth`) of the caption itself. I'd like to use the `label` and `caption` of the `lstlisting` environment.

Any idea?

Note: I may post more details sometime later.

**EDIT**: Well, I just achieved a partial solution:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[label={lst:stuff},
caption={Very large Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption.}]
Stuff
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\ref{lst:stuff}
```

Now the problem is that large captions will begin break lines and not fill the entire `\linewidth` since only 70% percent (`0.7\linewidth`) of it is available (this is required in order to make the listing centered by eye).

Any ideas?

**EDIT 2**: I guess `\captionof{lstlisting}{Caption}` will have to do the trick.

**EDIT 3**: Complete solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
Stuff
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\captionof{lstlisting}{Caption.}
\label={lst:stuff}
\end{figure}

\ref{lst:stuff}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption={Stuff},label=listofstuff]
Stuff
\end{lstlisting}` is a floating listing that cannot be broken across pages.

Comment: Yes, but it is not centered. Adding this requirement to the mix complicates things, since many solutions (e.g., `minipage`) are not floatable.

Comment: Could you please post some [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), to get people started on solving your problem?

Comment: @Jubobs I just added more details.

Comment: Good. Now please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs Just did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xleftmargin` and `xrightmargin` to give a "centered" looking to your listing.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[%
  float=htbp,
  caption={Very large Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption Caption.},
  label={lst:stuff},
  xleftmargin=2cm,
  xrightmargin=2cm
  ]
Stuff
\end{lstlisting}

This is my listing no. \ref{lst:stuff}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Adjust `2cm` to better fit your needs.

Comment: Much cleaner solution. Didn't know about the margin arguments. Thanks!